# What happens if a TCP implementation retransmits different data?

Tags: networking, tcp

No sensible TCP implementation would do this, but does anyone know what happens in practice if a TCP endpoint retransmits different data for particular sequence numbers?  I couldn't find anything in RFC 793 or RFC 9293 that specifies particular behavior, and a Google search didn't come up with any discussion of the topic.

For example, in a session between A and B:

1. A->B - Octets 0-99
2. A->B - Octets 100-199 - Lost (or intentionally never sent)
3. A->B - Octets 200-299
4. B->A - ACK 100
5. Retransmission timeout
6. A->B - Different octets 200-299
7. A->B - Octets 100-199

Does anyone know of any discussion of how actual implementations would respond to this (eg, always using the first copy) or if there is variation among them?  Does this differ if the sender changes the packet boundaries (eg, the retransmitted packets send 100-149 and then 150-249, where 200-249 are different than before)?

Answer (score 1):

An endpoint should only retransmit if the the other indicates it has not received the data or it does not receive an ack for the packets. If you are asking what happens when data is retransmitted when it has ALREADY BEEN RECEIVED, then most likely the other end will discard the duplicate packets - but the reality may vary by implementation; Behaviour in such a scenario is undefined.

Comment: Right, the question is if anyone knows what TCP implementations actually do in such a scenario.

Comment: "may vary by implementation; Behaviour in such a scenario is undefined."